# There are infinitely many choices of $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ such that $f(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)\neq 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm trying to solve this exercise in the page 10 of this [book](http://bookre.org/reader?file=1506398&pg=22)

[image]

Maybe I'm forgetting something, but I couldn't solve this exercise, I need a hint or something to begin to solve this question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Suppose you don't have infinitely many choices of $X$ so that $f(X)\not=0$. You therefore have finitely many choices of $X$ so that $f(X)\not=0$ so you have infinitely many choices of $X$ so that $f(X)=0$. So your polynomial has infinitely many roots so it is $\Bbb 0$. (I never used a field other than $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ but that must be how you prove it)

Comment: @xavierm02 the problem is I think I can't use the fundamental theorem of algebra here

Comment: @xavierm02, $f(X_1, X_2) = X_1 - X_2$ has infinitely many roots over an infinite field, so what?

Comment: @xavierm02 This is only the base case $n = 1$.
But you can continue via induction by writing $f \in K[X_1, \ldots X_{n+1}]$ as a finite sum $f = \sum_{i \ge 0} f_i \cdot X_n^i$ with $f_i \in K[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$. Maybe you want to go from here..

Comment: @Andreas Caranti : That's why I only used one variable. And don't you have $K[X,Y]\cong K[X][Y]$? So then you can apply it again by replacing $K$ by $K[X]$, can't you?

Comment: @xavierm02, you mean, as in my answer?

Comment: @xavierm02 Well, it's the right idea, but you have to be careful as you change from a field $K$ to an integral domain $K[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$... If you were right, you would have proven only to produce a finite number of roots, which you don't - shown by the example of Andreas Caranti.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deal  with the case $n = 1$ first. Here you use that a non-zero polynomial in one variable over a field has only finitely many roots.

When $n > 1$, argue by induction.

> (Thanks to **user78535** for suggesting some extra care here.)

If $X_1$ does not appear in $f$, then we have a polynomial in $n-1$ variables, and induction applies.

If $X_1$ does appear in $f$, write $f$ as a polynomial in $X_1$, with coefficients in $K[X_2, \dots, X_n]$. Clearly the coefficient of one of the powers $X_1^i$, for $i > 0$ has to be non-zero as a polynomial. Thus by induction there are infinitely many choices of $(\alpha_{2}, \dots, \alpha_{n}) \in (K \setminus \Lambda)^{n-1}$ for which this coefficient is non-zero as an element of $K$, when evaluated at $(\alpha_{2}, \dots, \alpha_{n})$.

Now appealing to the case $n = 1$, for each such choice of $(\alpha_{2}, \dots, \alpha_{n})$ there are infinitely many choices of $\alpha_{1}$ such that $f(\alpha_{1}, \dots, \alpha_{n}) \ne 0$.

Comment: Do you know how can I find such theorem for the case $n=1$? or the proof is direct?

Comment: @user42912, it is a standard fact that a non-zero polynomial $f$ over a field $F$ has only finitely many roots in $F$. First prove that $a \in F$ is a root of $f$ iff $x - a$ divides $f$. So if $a_1$ is a root, we have $f = (x-a_1) f_2$ for some polynomial $f_2$. Now if $f_2$ has a root $a_2 \in F$, then $f = (x-a_1)(x-a_2) f_3$. You end up with $f = (x-a_1) (x-a_2) \dots (x-a_k) f_{k+1}$, where $f_{k+1}$ has no roots in $F$. Now if $a$ is a root of $f$, we have $0 = f(a) = (a-a_1) (a-a_2) \cdots (a-a_k) f_{k+1}(a)$, and since $F$ is a field, one of the factors $a-a_i$ is zero, so $a = a_i$.

Comment: @user42912, so this shows that $f$ has at most $k \le \operatorname{degree}(f)$ roots in $F$.

Comment: The problem is the author didn't say anything yet about degrees and your solution uses implicitly the fact that when we divide $f$ by (x-a), $f=q(x)\cdot (x-a)$, where $q$ is of less degree of $f$. Your question is completely right, but I don't know if I can use this, I thought that the solution of this exercise is a straightforward use of the concepts and theorems the author has just developed so far.

Comment: I think you should say more to justify why you can choose a specialization where the coefficients are not all zero.

Comment: @user78535, quite right, thanks, will fix.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the case $\,n=1\,$ is clear, by a polynomial $\neq 0\,$ over a field has no more roots than its degree. For $\,n>1,\,$ write $f = c_k\, x_n^k + \cdots + c_0,\ c_i \in K[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}],\ c_k\neq 0.\,$ By induction we can specialize $\,(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}) = (a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1})\in (K \setminus \Lambda)^{n-1}$ so  the leading coeff $\,c_k\,$ stays $\ne 0,\,$ yielding $\, 0\ne g(x_n) = f(a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1},x_n) \in K[x_n].\,$ By induction there are infinitely many $\, a_n \in K \setminus \Lambda\,$ such that $\,g(a_n) = f(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \ne 0.\ \ $ **QED**